# Concat produces all NaN for a column of second dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

This is how I replaced the NaNs in the two dataframes,

```
df_max.fillna(0, inplace=True)
df_min.fillna(0, inplace=True)
```

This is how I concat and create a calculated column

```
df_max.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_min.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_combine = pd.concat([df_max, df_min], ignore_index = True)


df_combine['Range'] = df_combine['Maximum temperature (Degree C)'] - df_combine['Minimum temperature (Degree C)']
df_combine.head()
```

But I stil get NaN value for all rows in some columns.
[image]

Comment: Can you provide sample data for `df_max` and `df_min`?

Comment: @GunJack Can you add some sample data (original) for df_max and df_min data frames, pls as copyable code? this would be very helpful to identify your problem.

Comment: You should add `axis=1` to join the dataframes side by side.
`df_combine = pd.concat([df_max, df_min], axis=1, ignore_index = True)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add `axis=1` concatenate the dataframes by column and remove `ignore_index=True` to keep the column name.

```
df_combine = pd.concat([df_max, df_min], axis=1)
```

As there are repeated columns, `pd.merge` might work better, it works like sql join.

```
df_combine = pd.merge(df_max, df_min, on=['Year', 'Month', 'Product Code'], how='outer')
```

By default, axis=0 which means the dataframes are concatenated by row.

**Example**

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,3],[11,12,13]], columns=['a','b','c'])
df1 

    a   b   c
0   1   2   3
1  11  12  13 

df2 = pd.DataFrame([[1,2,6],[14,15,16]], columns=['a','b','f'])
df2
    a   b   f
0   1   2   6
1  14  15  16
```

```
pd.concat([df1, df2], ignore_index = True)
    a   b     c     f
0   1   2   3.0   NaN
1  11  12  13.0   NaN
2   1   2   NaN   6.0
3  14  15   NaN  16.0

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1, ignore_index = True)
    0   1   2   3   4   5
0   1   2   3   1   2   6
1  11  12  13  14  15  16

pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1)
    a   b   c   a   b   f
0   1   2   3   1   2   6
1  11  12  13  14  15  16

pd.merge(df1, df2, on=['a','b'], how='outer')
    a   b     c     f
0   1   2   3.0   6.0
1  11  12  13.0   NaN
2  14  15   NaN  16.0
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but both of the dataframe contain some columns that are similar. For example 'Year', 'Month'  and 'Product Code'. Adding axis=1 results in duplicating these columns. This is an issue as I wish to use groupby on column Year.

Comment: In this case, `pd.merge` might be better

Answer (score 0):

I think you want:

```
df_combine = pd.concat([df_max, df_min], ignore_index = True, axis=1)
```